# Error when trying to call requestPermissions method from BeaconWallet in VueJS 3 & Vite

Tags: beacon

(SOLVED) When trying to call requestPermissions method from an instance of BeaconWallet class using VueJS version 3 & Vite bundler, an error is displayed: "Uncaught TypeError: Transform is undefined":

```
Uncaught TypeError: Transform is undefined
CipherBase index.js:7
Hash browser.js:9
createHash browser.js:29
sha256x2 index.js:8
encode base.js:9
getSenderId get-sender-id.ts:14
__awaiter8 @taquito_beacon-wallet.js:5716
__awaiter8 @taquito_beacon-wallet.js:5698
getSenderId get-sender-id.ts:11
getOwnAppMetadata Client.ts:155
fulfilled @taquito_beacon-wallet.js:5807
promise callback*step @taquito_beacon-wallet.js:5820
.
.
.
```

Other possible similar errors might be:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Buffer is undefined
Uncaught TypeError: Stream is undefined
```

Is there any workaround to solve this issue?
I also tried on different framework (React) and got the exact same error.
I tried on Windows and Linux with same results.

Please, help.

Answer (score 2):

This issue is related to the fact that certain libraries require node modules that are actually meant to use for the backend. Since most modern bundlers do not polyfill these node modules by default anymore (because they are usually for frontend) so you must include them in your config.

Since you tried with React here is a minimal working config for Vite-React. I am sure this can be done better but it should do the trick.

**Vite Config TS:**

```
 import { defineConfig } from "vite";
    import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react-swc";
    import inject from "@rollup/plugin-inject";
    
    // https://vitejs.dev/config/
    export default defineConfig({
      define: {
        global: {},
      },
      plugins: [react()],
      resolve: {
        alias: {
          stream: "stream-browserify",
          os: "os-browserify/browser",
          util: "util",
          process: "process/browser",
          buffer: "buffer",
        },
      },
    });
```

**package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "template-vite-react",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@rollup/plugin-inject": "^5.0.3",
    "@taquito/beacon-wallet": "^15.1.0",
    "@taquito/taquito": "^15.1.0",
    "@types/node": "^18.14.6",
    "buffer": "^6.0.3",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "stream-browserify": "^3.0.0",
    "events": "^3.3.0",
    "util": "^0.12.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.0.28",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.11",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react-swc": "^3.2.0",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5",
    "vite": "^4.1.4"
  }
}
```

If you encounter any issues please let me know in the comments.

Comment: Thank you very much for your contribution. I spent so many hours trying to figure it out with no clue. This will help other Tezos developers. Sure thing.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is not related to dependencies versions, framework, nor operating system. After having a great conversation with Claude Barde, he has oriented me that this is something that regards the type of bundler that is being used.

So, each bundler (webpack, vite, etc) will require different tweakings to work with taquito/airgap/beacon-wallet.

Here is the vite.config.js file that worked for me (VueJS 3 + Vite):

```
import { defineConfig, mergeConfig } from "vite";
import path from "path";
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default ({ command }) => {
  const isBuild = command === "build";
  return defineConfig({
    plugins: [vue()],
    define: {
      global: {}
    },
    build: {
      target: "esnext",
      commonjsOptions: {
        transformMixedEsModules: true
      }
    },
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        // dedupe @airgap/beacon-sdk
        // I almost have no idea why it needs `cjs` on dev and `esm` on build, but this is how it works ‍♂️
        "@airgap/beacon-sdk": path.resolve(
          path.resolve(),
          `./node_modules/@airgap/beacon-sdk/dist/${
            isBuild ? "esm" : "cjs"
          }/index.js`
        ),
        // polyfills
        "readable-stream": "vite-compatible-readable-stream",
        stream: "vite-compatible-readable-stream"
      }
    }
  });
};
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .vue,.js,.jsx,.cjs,.mjs --fix --ignore-path .gitignore"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@airgap/beacon-sdk": "^3.3.4",
    "@taquito/beacon-wallet": "^16.0.1",
    "@taquito/taquito": "^16.0.1",
    "buffer": "^6.0.3",
    "vue": "^3.2.47",
    "vue-router": "^4.1.6",
    "vite-compatible-readable-stream": "^3.6.1",
    "events": "^3.3.0"**
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8.34.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.9.0",
    "vite": "^4.1.4"
  }
}
```

It will be required different configuration for React or Svelte!
Also, depending if you are using Javascript or Typescript, configuration will change.

Anyways, this **SOLVED** the issue.

A live example on github can be found here:

https://github.com/claudebarde/taquito-bundlers-testing/tree/main/vitejs